# After Transferred IOS App], No profiles for 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' were found Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

We receive an App which is existing on App Store and transferred by 3rd Party.

And We had met the issues on the following picture:

**1.  Failed to create provisioning profile.**

There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

**2.  No profiles for 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' were found**

Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.
Picture How to handle this??

How to handle this situation??

[image: Picture]

Comment: Just signIn with the particular account and import the profile. May works.

Answer (score 1):

Go to  Xcode -> preferences -> Sign in with perticular apple account -> Download Manual Profiles

Comment: do you have valid certificates and profiles in your apple developer account?

Comment: i didn't find any provisioning profiles in my Apple Developer there.
only Got App ID and Certificate for this target.
This is New App ID and get an App from other App ID

Comment: https://hyperpad.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204378199-Create-a-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile
pls follow this steps

Answer (score 0):

My MacBook was once registered with the Apple Development programme, using Apple ID 'A'. When i tried to sign the app with Apple ID 'B', Xcode seems to insist on using the profile for Apple ID 'A' to sign the app. Hence causing the error on the signing tab:

Failed to create provisioning profile.
There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

No profiles for 'Apple ID B.' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'Apple ID B.'

I then created another Adm user on the MacBook with Apple ID 'B', signed in as 'B' & re-created the app in Xcode.  I also added Apple ID 'A' in the Xcode preferences. When I selected the Team' as  (Personal Team) - Apple ID Á', & set Bundle Identifier as 'Applie ID 'A'_domain_name..' . The 'Signing error ...' went & it started to work with USB & WI-FI with my iPhone8+.